# Seksaj proporcioj en la komenco de Esperanto

Tags: culture, movado

Mi legis [ĉi tiun demandon](https://esperanto.stackexchange.com/questions/829/what-is-the-gender-ratio-of-the-esperanto-community) pri seksaj proporcioj en la nuna tempo kaj pensis pri la infaneco de Esperanto. En la mondo, tiom multe ŝanĝiĝis por la seksoj ekde la 1880-aj jaroj. Kiel aspektis la seksaj proporcioj en la komenco de nia lingvo?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Mi ĵus ekzamenis la [nomaron](http://data.onb.ac.at/dtl/6164994) kompilitan dum la unua Universala Kongreso en Bulonjo en 1905. (Vi povas trovi kelkajn aliajn dokumentojn [ĉi tie](http://www.onb.ac.at/ev/collections/esperanto/23525.htm).)

Laŭ Vikipedio, tiun eventon ĉeestis 688 aliĝintoj. La presita listo enhavas 630 enskribojn, el kiuj 21 estas paroj (ne ĉiuj geedzoj), do ni havas liston de 651 nomoj.

Mi nombris 173 virinojn el tiuj 651 homoj, do la proporcio estis ĉirkaŭ 27 %, kio ŝajnas al mi kiel relative granda nombro, konsidere la malhelpojn de vojaĝado por tiutempaj virinoj, kaj la ĝeneralan sintenon pri la partoprenado de virinoj en la intelekta mondo.

Estis 97 ĉeestantoj kiuj loĝis en Bulonjo mem. El tiuj, 49 estis virinoj. Tiu fakto sugestas ke la reala proporcio eble estis tre proksima al 50 %. Miaj legoj de la plej fruaj revuoj, konsidere la eraon, jam donis al mi impreson ke tio estus tute kredebla. La Esperanto-movado ĉiam asociiĝis al la movadoj pri paco kaj internacieco, kaj antaŭ la unua mondmilito, tiuj estis plej forte subtenataj de virinoj.

Answer (score 4):

Tre dependas de la lando. La plej fruaj pioniroj preskaŭ ĉie estis viroj, sed almenaŭ en Danio virinoj ludis ŝlosilajn rolojn en la starigo de la unuaj asocioj (Marie Schrøder kaj Margrethe Noll estas konataj nomoj).

Comment: Dankon pro la respondo kaj bonvenon al Stack Exchange!

Answer (score 1):

Mi ne scias pri la proporcioj, sed la unuan nomon de la fruaj (eble ne komencaj) jaroj, kiun mi memoris estis tiu de [Verda Majo](https://eo.wikipedia.org/wiki/Verda_Majo). Vi eble povas legi ĉi paĝon por trovi pliajn inajn esperantistojn de la fruaj jaroj: https://eo.wikipedia.org/wiki/Projekto:Viza%C4%9Doj